# How to implement auto save for a form?

Tags: angular

I plan on using ReactiveForms with the help of FormBuilder. And I'm wondering in which way auto save can be implemented. I need the following behaviour:

There's no submit button on a page. When user makes changes within a form, the data is automatically saved and gets sent to a server.

How can this be achieved in Angular2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `valueChanges` event of your form. Then simply check if the form is valid and then save your data on every change.

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({...});
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => { this.saveMyFormValue(val); });
```

`valueChanges` is a property on the abstract class `AbstractControl`. `FormGroup`, `FormControl` and `FormArray` all implement `AbstractControl`, meaning that you can also subscribe to this event for individual form controls if you'd wish to.

Answer (score 1):

I place the code below in the constructor of my Profile Component.
I use the delay method that is available to give a bit of time to autosave.

Then if the the form is valid and if the form is dirty,
I call my saveProfile method and reset the form.

Here is the code :

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
});

this.form.valueChanges
  .delay(6000)
  .subscribe(() => {
    if (this. form.valid && this.form.touched) {
      this.saveForm();
      this.form.reset()
    }
  });
```

I hope this helps. Also open to a better way to do this if possible.

Comment: You will get: Property 'delay' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
With newer versions of angular you have to add it to the pipe